# How to setup a private git repository?

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, git

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and created a git server and gave some users access to one repos I created.
I have trouble to download the repos using open SSH through command line, no putty nothing.

I am using this command to download the repos called training :

`ssh://username@xx.xx.xx.xx:22/srv/git/training.git` and I tried a lot like

```
ssh://username@xx.xx.xx.xx:22/srv/git/training.git training
```

Using this tutorial : [ted felix git server](http://tedfelix.com/software/git-server.html)

The error I get is this :

```
fatal: '/srv/git/training/training' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

My suggestion is, that my repos is not setup correctly.

or I made a mistake with this ssh keys.
Any Ideas? I can provide all information you need, just let me know what's missing.

EDIT :
It works using the command line (git bash) ... intereseting

Output as requested of folder permissions

```
XXXXXX@DefaultEnvironment:~$ ls -la /svr/git/training
total 16
drwxr-sr-x 3 root      git 4096 Feb  4 12:55 .
drwxrwsr-x 4 XXXXXX    git 4096 Feb  4 12:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      git    9 Feb  4 12:55 catchmeifyoucan
drwxrwsr-x 8 root      git 4096 Feb  4 12:56 .git
```

Comment: Can you post output of `ls -la /srv/git/training.git`?

Comment: sure, posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The git repo you've created isn't a bare repository. A bare repository is a repo without the working tree.

From [git-scm](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server)

> Now, you can set up an empty repository for them by running git init
>   with the --bare option, which initializes the repository without a
>   working directory:

You can create a bare repo with:

```
`git init --bare <project name>`
```

Transforming a normal repo into a bare repo is not that hard, you can your best answer on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-git-repository-from-normal-to-bare)

Comment: give that sir a prize or price? why not both !? Totally saved my ass, but I still don't know why I could clone it before through command line.

Comment: I've had this problem a few years ago and I know how this problem kept me busy for a long times.